# É possível fazer bordas arredondadas no ComboBox do Windows Forms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, visual-studio-2017

Estou fazendo uma interface no Windows Forms do C# (Usando o Visual Studio 2017) que tinha projetado no Figma com um ComboBox, tinha projetado as bordas dele arredondadas, consegui fazer a alteração de várias características dele com um [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5V6ZD2mAUw8&t=118s) que vi no youtube, mas não achei em lugar algum um meio de fazer as bordas do ComboBox poderem ser customizáveis, ou seja, poder colocar um arredondamento, seja de um ângulo fixo ou customizável, só consegui fazer elas poderem trocar de cor e grossura mas não arredondamento. Isso é possível? (o que quero fazer com a borda é basicamente o que mostra na imagem que eu coloquei)

coloquei o código onde estou tentando implemetar essa borda arredondada abaixo da imagem.

[image: ComboBox do Projeto do Figma]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Design;


namespace PIM_4_Desktop.Controles_Personalizados
{
    [DefaultEvent("OnSelectedIndexChanged")]
    class ComboBoxPers: UserControl
    {
        //Fields
        private Color backColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        private Color iconColor = Color.MediumSlateBlue;
        private Color listBackColor = Color.FromArgb(230, 228, 245);
        private Color listTextColor = Color.DimGray;
        private Color borderColor = Color.MediumSlateBlue;
        private int borderSize = 2;
        private int borderRadius = 10;

        //Items
        private ComboBox cmbList;
        private Label lblText;
        private Button btnIcon;

        //Events
        public event EventHandler OnSelectedIndexChanged;//Default event

        //Constructor
        public ComboBoxPers()
        {
            cmbList = new ComboBox();
            lblText = new Label();
            btnIcon = new Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();

            //ComboBox: Dropdown list
            cmbList.BackColor = listBackColor;
            cmbList.Font = new Font(this.Font.Name, 10F);
            cmbList.ForeColor = listTextColor;
            cmbList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);//Default event
            cmbList.TextChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_TextChanged);//Refresh text

            //Button: Icon
            btnIcon.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            btnIcon.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btnIcon.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            btnIcon.BackColor = backColor;
            btnIcon.Size = new Size(30, 30);
            btnIcon.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            btnIcon.Click += new EventHandler(Icon_Click);//Open dropdown list
            btnIcon.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Icon_Paint);//Draw icon

            //Label: Text
            lblText.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lblText.AutoSize = false;
            lblText.BackColor = backColor;
            lblText.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            lblText.Padding = new Padding(8, 0, 0, 0);
            lblText.Font = new Font(this.Font.Name, 10F);
            //->Attach label events to user control event
            lblText.Click += new EventHandler(Surface_Click);//Select combo box
            lblText.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(Surface_MouseEnter);
            lblText.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(Surface_MouseLeave);

            //User Control
            this.Controls.Add(lblText);//2
            this.Controls.Add(btnIcon);//1
            this.Controls.Add(cmbList);//0
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(200, 30);
            this.Size = new Size(200, 30);
            this.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
            this.Padding = new Padding(borderSize);//Border Size
            this.Font = new Font(this.Font.Name, 10F);
            base.BackColor = borderColor; //Border Color
            this.ResumeLayout();
            AdjustComboBoxDimensions();
        }

        //Properties
        //-> Appearance
        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public int BorderRadius
        {
            get { return borderRadius; }
            set
            {
                borderRadius = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public new Color BackColor
        {
            get { return backColor; }
            set
            {
                backColor = value;
                lblText.BackColor = backColor;
                btnIcon.BackColor = backColor;
            }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public Color IconColor
        {
            get { return iconColor; }
            set
            {
                iconColor = value;
                btnIcon.Invalidate();//Redraw icon
            }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public Color ListBackColor
        {
            get { return listBackColor; }
            set
            {
                listBackColor = value;
                cmbList.BackColor = listBackColor;
            }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public Color ListTextColor
        {
            get { return listTextColor; }
            set
            {
                listTextColor = value;
                cmbList.ForeColor = listTextColor;
            }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return borderColor; }
            set
            {
                borderColor = value;
                base.BackColor = borderColor; //Border Color
            }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public int BorderSize
        {
            get { return borderSize; }
            set
            {
                borderSize = value;
                this.Padding = new Padding(borderSize);//Border Size
                AdjustComboBoxDimensions();
            }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public override Color ForeColor
        {
            get { return base.ForeColor; }
            set
            {
                base.ForeColor = value;
                lblText.ForeColor = value;
            }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public override Font Font
        {
            get { return base.Font; }
            set
            {
                base.Font = value;
                lblText.Font = value;
                cmbList.Font = value;//Optional
            }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public string Texts
        {
            get { return lblText.Text; }
            set { lblText.Text = value; }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Aparência")]
        public ComboBoxStyle DropDownStyle
        {
            get { return cmbList.DropDownStyle; }
            set
            {
                if (cmbList.DropDownStyle != ComboBoxStyle.Simple)
                    cmbList.DropDownStyle = value;
            }
        }
        //Properties
        //-> Data
        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Dados")]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ListControlStringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [MergableProperty(false)]
        public ComboBox.ObjectCollection Items
        {
            get { return cmbList.Items; }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Dados")]
        [AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource))]
        [DefaultValue(null)]
        public object DataSource
        {
            get { return cmbList.DataSource; }
            set { cmbList.DataSource = value; }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Dados")]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ListControlStringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public AutoCompleteStringCollection AutoCompleteCustomSource
        {
            get { return cmbList.AutoCompleteCustomSource; }
            set { cmbList.AutoCompleteCustomSource = value; }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Dados")]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(AutoCompleteSource.None)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        public AutoCompleteSource AutoCompleteSource
        {
            get { return cmbList.AutoCompleteSource; }
            set { cmbList.AutoCompleteSource = value; }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Dados")]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(AutoCompleteMode.None)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        public AutoCompleteMode AutoCompleteMode
        {
            get { return cmbList.AutoCompleteMode; }
            set { cmbList.AutoCompleteMode = value; }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Dados")]
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return cmbList.SelectedItem; }
            set { cmbList.SelectedItem = value; }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Dados")]
        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return cmbList.SelectedIndex; }
            set { cmbList.SelectedIndex = value; }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Dados")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        [TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldConverter, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
        public string DisplayMember
        {
            get { return cmbList.DisplayMember; }
            set { cmbList.DisplayMember = value; }
        }

        [Category("Trabalho PIM 4 - Dados")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public string ValueMember
        {
            get { return cmbList.ValueMember; }
            set { cmbList.ValueMember = value; }
        }

        //Private methods
        private void AdjustComboBoxDimensions()
        {
            cmbList.Width = lblText.Width;
            cmbList.Location = new Point()
            {
                X = this.Width - this.Padding.Right - cmbList.Width,
                Y = lblText.Bottom - cmbList.Height
            };
        }

        private GraphicsPath GetFigurePath(Rectangle rect, float radius)
        {
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            float curveSize = radius * 2F;

            path.StartFigure();
            path.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, curveSize, curveSize, 180, 90);
            path.AddArc(rect.Right - curveSize, rect.Y, curveSize, curveSize, 270, 90);
            path.AddArc(rect.Right - curveSize, rect.Bottom - curveSize, curveSize, curveSize, 0, 90);
            path.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Bottom - curveSize, curveSize, curveSize, 90, 90);
            path.CloseFigure();
            return path;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pevent);

            Rectangle rectSurface = this.ClientRectangle;
            Rectangle rectBorder = Rectangle.Inflate(rectSurface, -borderSize, -borderSize);
            int smoothSize = 2;
            if (borderSize > 0)
                smoothSize = borderSize;

            if (borderRadius > 2) //Botão Redondo
            {
                using (GraphicsPath pathSurface = GetFigurePath(rectSurface, borderRadius))
                using (GraphicsPath pathBorder = GetFigurePath(rectBorder, borderRadius - borderSize))
                using (Pen penSurface = new Pen(this.Parent.BackColor, smoothSize))
                using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
                {
                    pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    //Superfície do Botão
                    this.Region = new Region(pathSurface);
                    //Desenha a superfície da borda para um resultado em alta definição
                    pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(penSurface, pathSurface);

                    //Borda do Botão                    
                    if (borderSize >= 1)
                        //Controle de Desenho da Borda
                        pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(penBorder, pathBorder);
                }
            }
            else //Botão Normal
            {
                pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
                //Superfície do Botão
                this.Region = new Region(rectSurface);
                //Borda do Botão
                if (borderSize >= 1)
                {
                    using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
                    {
                        penBorder.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
                        pevent.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penBorder, 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Button_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (borderRadius > this.Height)
                borderRadius = this.Height;
        }

        //Event methods

        //-> Default event
        private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (OnSelectedIndexChanged != null)
                OnSelectedIndexChanged.Invoke(sender, e);
            //Refresh text
            lblText.Text = cmbList.Text;
        }

        //-> Draw icon
        private void Icon_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //Fields
            int iconWidht = 14;
            int iconHeight = 6;
            var rectIcon = new Rectangle((btnIcon.Width - iconWidht) / 2, (btnIcon.Height - iconHeight) / 2, iconWidht, iconHeight);
            Graphics graph = e.Graphics;

            //Draw arrow down icon
            using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(iconColor, 2))
            {
                graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                path.AddLine(rectIcon.X, rectIcon.Y, rectIcon.X + (iconWidht / 2), rectIcon.Bottom);
                path.AddLine(rectIcon.X + (iconWidht / 2), rectIcon.Bottom, rectIcon.Right, rectIcon.Y);
                graph.DrawPath(pen, path);
            }
        }

        //-> Items actions
        private void Icon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Open dropdown list
            cmbList.Select();
            cmbList.DroppedDown = true;
        }
        private void Surface_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Attach label click to user control click
            this.OnClick(e);
            //Select combo box
            cmbList.Select();
            if (cmbList.DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)
                cmbList.DroppedDown = true;//Open dropdown list
        }
        private void ComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Refresh text
            lblText.Text = cmbList.Text;
        }

        //->Attach label events to user control event
        private void Surface_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.OnMouseLeave(e);
        }

        private void Surface_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.OnMouseEnter(e);
        }
        //::::+

        //Overridden methods
        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);
            AdjustComboBoxDimensions();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A classe `GraphicsPath` de `System.Drawing.Drawing2D` permite você trabalhar com curvas no windows forms.

Tenho um método onde coloca uma pequena borda igual ao da imagem.

```
public static class CustomControlExtensions
{
    public static void RoundBorder(this Control control, int radius = 20)
    {
        control.Paint += (o, e) => OnPaint(control, e, radius);
    }

    private static void OnPaint(Control control, PaintEventArgs e, int radius)
    {
        using GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new();
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphicsPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(0, 0, radius, radius), 180, 90);
        graphicsPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(control.Width - radius, 0, radius, radius), -90, 90);
        graphicsPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(control.Width - radius, control.Height - radius, radius, radius), 0, 90);
        graphicsPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(0, control.Height - radius, radius, radius), 90, 90);
        graphicsPath.SetMarkers();
        control.Region = new Region(graphicsPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Irei testar implementar esse código. Não sei muito sobre o C#, sou mais fazer o front-end de Web, então, se eu precisar alterar o ângulo, em qual das linhas eu teria que mudar os números?

Comment: eu tentei implementar esse código e não consegui fazer funcionar, o que eu deveria fazer?

Comment: Infelizmente para alterar o angulo nesse método você precisaria alterar todas as linhas praticamente. é um código pronto para uma borda simples em um controle. Se você quiser um angulo maior eu posso tentar modifica-lo e editar a resposta.

Comment: Testei em um ComboBox e funcionou, como você esta tentando implementar?

Comment: estou tentando implementar num código já pronto. Mas como não tenho muito conhecimento em C# eu não estou conseguindo adaptado direito. Tentei também implementar trocando algumas coisas em um código onde há um get e set para uma categoria para ser possível ter uma opção de personalizar o borderRadius

Comment: vou editar a pergunta e colocar o código onde estou tentando implementar

Comment: @BrenoLeonetti Editei minha resposta permitindo passar um valor para o angulo da borda